# 12.04 LTS won't boot after nvidia driver upgrade

Tags: 12.04, boot, drivers, nvidia, live-cd

I wanted to use the most recent nvidia-319(I think) drivers so that Steam would stop complaining about my drivers.  I selected the 319 drivers in the System Hardware menu and rebooted.  The system hung on reboot for several minutes so I performed a hard-shutdown. After the system came back online, it prompted me for my MySQLServer login (its never done that before). I forgot the credentials so I hard-restarted again and this time it boots to a black screen with a flashing cursor on the top left. NOTHING THAT I TYPE IS SHOWN ON SCREEN.  When I hit the power button, it says various things are shutting down/stopping and then the system turns off.

My question is how can I use a LiveCD to revert this driver change? Or is there another (better) method?   This is the first time that I have broken my Ubuntu in 4 years :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Reinstalling your drivers to the current version will solve this:

You will have to boot normally, and when the black screen appears, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Login, then use the following commands.

First remove all the old drivers:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Then reinstall the current drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Reboot, and your're good to go!

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: What options do I need to choose from the LiveCD to be able to gain terminal access?  The flashing cursor does not show anything that I type.

Comment: You shouldn't do this from the live cd, but from when you boot "normally". I've updated my answer.

Comment: This is what I get after trying to purge:  E: Unable to locate package nvidia-bug-report.log.gz E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'nvidia-bug-report.log.gz'   I then tried to install current, it said I was running the current version and gave me the option to remove unnecessary packages, which I did. Rebooted and same black screen with cursor.

Answer (score 0):

When I was using 12.04 with nvidia  and had a problem  I would edit grub and add nomodeset and boot into vessa and then reinstall nvidia drivers. Usualy worked for me.I had to use nomodeset to run cd also
.